# Raspberry Pi restarts with Caffe Model

Tags: python, camera

I tried to run some python facial-detection script into my Raspberry Pi 3 with openVino installed openCV and Intel Movidius Neural Stick 2 Myriad. But when Myriad try to execute `net.forward()`, the raspberry collapse and restarts. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2

#Argumentos de la funcion
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

#Cargamos el modelo
print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_MYRIAD)

print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(2.0)

while(True):

    #Redimensiona a 400 pixeles
    retval, frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

    #Obtiene las dimensiones y las convierte a blob
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)), 1.0,(300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

    #Predicciones
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()

    cv2.imshow('Input image', cv2.flip(frame, 1))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

In a similar code without videoCapture, the `net.forward()` the script runs very well.

Thank you for your time and your answers :)

Comment: How much power does that intel stick draw from usb?

Comment: I don't know, maybe could be a reason, Im going to test with an iPad charger. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the following article, the Intel Movidius Neural Stick 2 Myriad draws about 0.18Amps through the USB port. So make sure the Pi power supply can accomplish this.

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/jokersys.com/2017/08/05/first-look-movidius-neural-compute-stick/amp/